# Velocity while falling from table

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, velocity, calculus, speed

> Suppose there is a chain of mass $m$ in a semicircular tube of radius $r$. If it's pushed, then find the velocity of the chain while leaving the tube.

This is a simple problem which we can do using conservation of energy, however my question isn't how to solve it, rather what is meant by velocity in this case. The distance which the chain is traversing is a circular path. Whereas velocity is the rate of change of displacement which is along a straight path. So what do we generally mean in this case? Is it speed or velocity? Since the particles of the chain are traversing distance along a circular path.

Comment: If you are familiar with calculus you know that velocity can be defined at an instantaneous point then there isn't any meaning to linear displacement there.

Answer (score 0):

We define velocity for instantaneous points . Velocity is $dS \over dt$ , where dS is infinitesimally small change in displacement and dt is similarly very small time . So it doesn't matter whether the chain is traversing in a circular path .